# Javascript async function throws error when using await

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, axios, vuejs3

I'm still beginner when it comes to JavaScript.
In my vuejs3 app I have the following situation (I assume knowing this is Vue is not important):

In my Vue app I have a method like this

```
async LoadBasicData()
{
    this.basicData = await window.LoadBasicData();
},
```

It calls a function in a different JavaScript file. The method looks a bit like this:

```
async function LoadBasicData()
{
    return new Promise(resolve =>
    {
        let result = Object.create(null);

        let url = 'MyFancyUrl';

        axios
            .get(url)
            .then((response) =>
            {
                result.data = response.data;

                result = await LoadBuildId(result);

                resolve(result);
            })
    });
}
```

The LoadBuildId function is looking very similar

```
async function LoadBuildId(result)
{
    return new Promise(resolve =>
    {
        let url = 'MySecondFancyUrl';

        axios
            .get(url)
            .then((response) =>
            {
                result.buildId = response.data;

                resolve(result);
            })
    });
}
```

From my understanding of all this async/await/promise this should be the correct way of doing it, but considering that it's not working I'm pretty sure there is something I have misunderstood
I'm getting the error "await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules" when calling LoadBuildId. I don't understand the error, as await is called in an async function

What am I doing wrong here? Why can't my async function call another async function? Or is there a better way?

I know there is at least one way to accomplish what I need, that is by using callbacks. I have been using it until now, but I'm not really a fan of it as it really makes the code unnecessary complicated.

Comment: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making 2 mistakes

- Wrapping the existing promise-related functionality with your own promise (see: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it))
- Mixing async/await with `then`

The code can be hugely simplified:

```
async function LoadBuildId(result)
{
    let url = 'MySecondFancyUrl';
    const response = await axios.get(url)
    result.buildId = response.data;
    return result;
}
```

and

```
async function LoadBasicData()
{
    let url = 'MyFancyUrl';
    let result = Object.create(null);

    const response = await axios.get(url);
    result = await LoadBuildId(result);
    return result;
}
```

To be honest, it can be simplified even further - theres no need to be constructing `result` objects just to set properties on it - you may as well just return the results from a call to `axios.get`

Comment: `Object.create(null)` is superfluous. `result` will always be overwritten with `result = await ...`

Comment: @Andreas hence my final paragraph

Comment: Then why add it in the first place?

Comment: @Andreas to keep the code as close as possible to the OP's original, whilst also pointing out the actual issue they were having.

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't see that it could be made like that. Sorry for the late response, I ended up sick with Covid-19 just after posting my question